# findPreference() returns null

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I'm trying to change the Toggle switch of a SwitchPreferenceCompat to true and false pragmatically. However, in SettingsFragment class the method ammendSwitchPreferenceSetting() the preference variable is always null, howeever if I call this method from within the onCreatePreferences() it will work, but I need to call it elsewhere.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        //will allow the user to go back to parent page of the application
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }

        public void ammendSwitchPreferenceSetting(String key, boolean value){
            //is always null for some reason
            SwitchPreferenceCompat preference =  findPreference(key);
            preference.setChecked(value);
        }

    }
}
```

```
 <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:enabled="true"
            android:summary="some summary"
            app:defaultValue="true"
            app:key="NetworkType"
            app:title="some title" />
```

And then I'm calling it from another class

```
SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment();
settingsFragment.ammendSwitchPreferenceSetting("NetworkType", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Kotlin, and this is how I can change the switch values.

```
val sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
sharedpref.putBoolean("NetworkType",false).apply()
```

In java, it will be like this

```
sharedpref prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
sharedpref.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("NetworkType",false);
editor.apply();
```

> Note: I didn't teste this Java version, but the concept is like that.